# Expand Sub menu when tabbing on keyboard

Tags: html, css, megamenu

I have a mega menu that I would like to make accessible. I would like the mega menu to expand when the user tabs through the menu.

At the moment when you tab through the menu I can see that it is in fact focusing on the sub menu items but the mega menu doesn't open.

Can anyone help me out with this?

What do I need to do to make the mega menu expand when the child items are focused?

```css
/*-- base styles --*/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
  &.mobile-menu-active {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
  }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}


/*-- header styles --*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #3e6fcb;
}


/*-- mega menu --*/

.mega-menu {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3e6fcb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*-- menu styles --*/

ul {
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  color: white;
  a {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: block;
    &:hover {
      +.mega-menu {
        height: auto;
      }
    }
  }
}

ul li ul li {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

ul ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

ul ul ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">1. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">1. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">1. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">1. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">1. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">1. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">1. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">2. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">2. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">2. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">2. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">2. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">2. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">2. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">3. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">3. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">3. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">3. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">3. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">3. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">3. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="">4. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">4. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">4. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">4. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">4. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">4. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">4. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">5. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">5. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">5. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">5. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">5. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">5. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">5. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">6. Level 1</a>
      <div class="mega-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">6. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">6. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">6. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">6. Level 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="">6. Level 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="">6. Level 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: couple things that could help: 1.) add `tab-index="0"` to the list-items/links. 2.) add keypress handlers with javaScript.

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to link they keydown function if it's tab, then add the classes that open the menu & focus on the first menu item, then on last menu-item if tab pressed focus on next top=level item and close menu... then you can also consider keypress handlers for the up/down/left/right keys.

Comment: Have you tried with :focus?

Comment: I've tried with :focus that just opens the mega menu but as soon as i tab again the parent loses focus to the mega menu closes again.